# Conversion Function

Tags: function, f#, type-conversion

I am trying to create a function that converts any number type to float32 and anything else to 0f.

I first tried using match on type, but the type system infers the type as boolean, even when I set the type as generic.

```
let numtype x =
    match box x with
    //| :? sbyte | :? byte | :? int16 | :? int32 | :? int64 | :? uint16 | :? uint32 | :? uint64 | :? nativeint | :? unativeint | :? decimal | :? double | :? float | :? float32 -> float 32 x
    | :? char | :? string | :? unit -> 0f
    | :? bool -> 0f
    | _ -> float32 x

numtype true
```

> Script1.fsx(63,9): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have **type 'int' but here has type 'bool'**

Then, I tried using a error catching, but it balks at converting from generic

```
let convToNum<'a> (x:'a) =
    try
        match x with
        | :? float32 -> x
    with
        //| :? System.Exception -> 0f
        | _ -> 0f

convToNum 1
```

> Script1.fsx(76,11): error FS0008: This runtime coercion or type test from **type 'a to float32** involves an indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. Runtime type tests are not allowed on some types. Further type annotations are needed.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

*updated based on comments*

Comment: Your first attempt doesn't with because `0` is an `int` literal. You need to replace it with `0f`. Or with `float32 0`

Comment: @FyodorSoikin That is a good catch, but it still does not work.  The error becomes
Script1.fsx(63,9): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    'int'    
but here has type
    'bool'

Comment: That means you have another typo that you're not showing us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're calling `float32` on the original `x` parameter instead of using the cast value. Try something like this instead:

```ml
let numtype (x : obj) =
    match x with
    | :? sbyte as x' -> float32 x'
    | :? int16 as x' -> float32 x'
    | :? int32 as x' -> float32 x'
    | :? int64 as x' -> float32 x'
    | :? uint32 as x' -> float32 x'
    | :? uint64 as x' -> float32 x'
    | :? nativeint as x' -> float32 x'
    | :? unativeint as x' -> float32 x'
    | :? decimal as x' -> float32 x'
    | :? double as x' -> float32 x'
    | :? float32 as x' -> x'
    | _ -> 0f
```

You can also use the built-in `System.Convert` type:

```ml
open System

let numtype (x : obj) =
    try Convert.ToSingle(x)
    with _ -> 0f
```